# SimpleXML Issue, Cannot Create Object (Works on php7.1 but fails on 7.2)

Tags: php, simplexml

I have a working XML parser setup using SimpleXML, when I copy the code across to the live environment it throws an error

```
<?php 
$myXMLData = trim(file_get_contents('php://input'));
$xml=simplexml_load_string($myXMLData) or die("Error: Cannot create object")
```

The only different between the 2 environments is the PHP version its working on PHP 7.1 but failing on 7.2

SimpleXML is enabled in both versions

I have added in:

```
try {
libxml_use_internal_errors(TRUE);
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($myXMLData);
echo '<pre>'.htmlspecialchars($xml->asXML()).'</pre>';

} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Caught exception: ' . $e->getMessage() . chr(10);
    echo 'Failed loading XML: ' . chr(10);
    foreach(libxml_get_errors() as $error) {
        echo '- ' . $error->message;
    }
}
```

This just gives a basic error:
Caught exception: String could not be parsed as XML
Failed loading XML:

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

The XML Being sent is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<cdr>
  <ID>9690579659</ID>
  <Distributor>ACME</Distributor>
  <DistributorID>11111111</DistributorID>
  <CustomerGroup>ACME Default</CustomerGroup>
  <Customer>447000000000</Customer>
  <CustomerID>13978539</CustomerID>
  <CustomerReference>447000000000</CustomerReference>
  <Subscriber> </Subscriber>
  <SubscriberID>13978540</SubscriberID>
  <SubscriberReference>8944538531004717134</SubscriberReference>
  <CreateTime>2022-05-25 13:49:43</CreateTime>
  <ConnectTime>2022-05-25 13:49:43</ConnectTime>
  <EndTime>2022-05-25 13:51:43</EndTime>
  <Type>gsm-data</Type>
  <Leg1>Data service</Leg1>
  <Leg1Country>United Kingdom</Leg1Country>
  <Leg1Type>mobile</Leg1Type>
  <Leg2/>
  <Leg2Country/>
  <Leg2Type/>
  <Duration>120</Duration>
  <Bytes>764</Bytes>
  <Outcome>successful</Outcome>
  <Narrative>Data Session (0.001 Mb consumed)</Narrative>
  <BuyCurrency bottom-up-level="1" top-down-level="2" supplying-distributor-id="111111111" consuming-distributor-id="7139428">GBP</BuyCurrency>
  <BuyAmount bottom-up-level="1" top-down-level="2" supplying-distributor-id="187715" consuming-distributor-id="7139428">0.0001</BuyAmount>
  <RetailCurrency bottom-up-level="0" top-down-level="3" supplying-distributor-id="7139428">GBP</RetailCurrency>
  <RetailAmount bottom-up-level="0" top-down-level="3" supplying-distributor-id="7139428">0.0001</RetailAmount>
  <Charges>
    <Charge top-down-level="3" bottom-up-level="0" supplying-distributor-id="7139428">
      <Currency>GBP</Currency>
      <Amount>0.0001</Amount>
      <Balance>-1.9778</Balance>
    </Charge>
  </Charges>
  <Legs>
    <Leg>
      <LegType>data</LegType>
      <Country ISOCode="GBR">United Kingdom</Country>
      <ZoneType>mobile</ZoneType>
      <Number/>
      <RouteNumber>44700000000</RouteNumber>
      <RateNumber>447000000000</RateNumber>
      <Identity mcc="204" mnc="04"/>
    </Leg>
  </Legs>
</cdr>
```

Comment: Without the XML is hard to tell. Character encoding might be something to look into.

Comment: Sorry Rolando, I added it in just now. Rookie error.

Comment: `<RateNumber>447000000000/RateNumber>` - is that closing tag actually mangled like this in your input data ...?

Comment: CBroe - No, sorry i must have deleted that out when santising the number, apologies

Comment: Doesn't matter which 7.2.x version I choose here, it appears to work fine with all those I tested: https://3v4l.org/F8Ebr#v7.2.34

Comment: Try and use `htmlspecialchars`on `$error->message`, otherwise the browser might "hide" parts of it when it contains any sort of tags.

Comment: Have you tried dumping `$myXMLData` before even trying to parse it as XML? Maybe your configuration is not passing through `php://input`